# LINQ: How to filter two expressions with OR, while both have conditions to include filter?

Tags: c#, linq

I know that `if (includeFilter) query = query.Where (...)` gives the same result as `query = query.Where (n => !includeFilter || <expression>)`.

But what if I have `<expression1>` and `<expression2>` and I want `query.Where (n => <expression1> || <expression2>)`? Except that there are `includeFilter1` and `includeFilter2` too.

Simply `query.Where (n => (!includeFilter1 || <expression1>) || (!includeFilter2 || <expression2>))` won't work, because in case `includeFilter1` is `false`, `<expression2>` will have no effect.

---

**Update:**

I just got to this solution:
```query.Where(n => !includeFilter1 || ).Union(query.Where(n => !includeFilter2 || ))```

I'm going to use it with IQueryable; is it OK? Is there a better solution?

---

**Update 2:**

I was wrong. What I needed was this:

```
var query1 = query.Where(n => !includeFilter1 || <expression1>)
var query2 = query.Where(n => !includeFilter2 || <expression2>)

if (includeFilter1 && includeFilter2)
    query = query1.Union(query2);
else if (includeFilter1)
    query = query1;
else if (includeFilter2)
    query = query2;
```

I couldn't come up with a more elegant way.

Comment: Are you looking for **xor**? `expression1 ^ expression2` which is `true` when *either* `expression1` is true *or* `expression2` is true, but not *both* of them?

Comment: what about this? `query = query.Where(n => includeFilter1 ? <expression1> : includeFilter2 ? <expression2> : false);` ?

Comment: @letsdoit Thanks. Which do you think is better? Your solution or this: ```query.Where(n => !includeFilter1 || <expression1>).Union(query.Where(n => !includeFilter2 || <expression2>))```

Comment: @Yusif better in terms of? My answer is simple and easy to understand.

Comment: @letsdoit Performance or readability for example. I don't know how linq works but I guess yours must be more performant.

Comment: @Yusif yes you’re right

Comment: @letsdoit Oh but it's not what I meant; in case includeFilter1, <expression1>, includeFilter2, <expression2> are true, false, true, true respectively, it will give false, which should give true. It must have been my poor English. Please see the post update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `.Union()` is best reserved for cases where you can't represent the logic of the filter in a single query, or when the data is being drawn from different sources in each part of the query. Each `.Union()` call most likely results in a separate query execution, which means the query optimizer has little to no chance to produce a reasonable execution plan.

Using `.Where(n => !includeFilter || <expression>)` is also less that optimal on the face of it. The expression tree will close over the `includeFilter` variable and may not be optimized particularly well depending on the ORM you're using. Best to avoid that where possible.

There are several options for this kind of query composition. The simplest, which works fine for a couple of entries, is this:

```
if (includeFilter1)
{
    if (includeFilter2)
        query = query.Where(q => <expression1> || <expression2>);
    else
        query =  query.Where(q => <expression1>);
}
else if (includeFilter2)
    query = query.Where(q => <expression2>);
```

Not very elegant perhaps, but it works just fine and only takes a few lines of code to implement... if `<expression1>` and `<expression2>` are known at compile time and aren't parameters to the method.

---

What I think you're looking for is a more generic way to handle filter expression composition. LINQ has some rather interesting expression handling and while expressions can be scary at first, once you get the hang of them you can do some quite cool things.

For instance, here's an extension (and a supporting class) that will take two predicates on the same type and join them with an `Or`:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions

public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        // Useful for chained or conditional composition:
        if (left is null)
            return right;
        if (right is null)
            return left;
        // Just in case:
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
            return left;
        
        // change right parameter references to match left
        var rightBody = ReplaceVisitor.Replace(right.Body, right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]);
        
        // build 'or' expression
        var body = Expression.OrElse(left.Body, rightBody);
        
        // Create lambda (function) for predicate
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, left.Parameters[0]);
        
        return result;
    }
}

// Helper class, replaces expression instances
// Used to get the right parameters in composed expressions.
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _from;
    private readonly Expression _to;
    
    private ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        _from = from;
        _to = to;
    }
    
    public override Expression Visit(Expression e) 
        => ReferenceEquals(e, _from) ? _to : base.Visit(e);
    
    public static T Replace<T>(T expression, Expression from, Expression to)
        where T : Expression
    {
        var visitor = new ReplaceVisitor(from, to);
        return (T)visitor.Visit(expression);
    }
}
```

(You can create a similar `.And()` extension using the `AndAlso` expression.)

Using that you can directly merge your filter expresions with an `Or` like so:

```
public IQueryable<T> ApplyFilters<T>(IQueryable<T> query, 
        bool useFilter1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate1,
        bool useFilter2, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate2
)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null;
    if (useFilter1)
        predicate = predicate.Or(predicate1);
    if (useFilter2)
        predicate = predicate.Or(predicate2);

    return predicate is null ? query : query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Or perhaps this:

```
public IQueryable<T> AnyOf<T>(IQueryable<T> query, params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] filters)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null;

    foreach (var filter in filters)
        predicate = predicate.Or(filter);

    return predicate is null ? query : query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Try it out, see if it fits your use case.

Comment: Thank you. I got my answer from the first part. And read the second part, but it's somewhat advanced for me; I should refer to it later when I know more about Expressions.

Comment: @Yusif It's a bit daunting at first, but once you understand how expressions work there are some things you can do that are otherwise very difficult.

Comment: Shouldn't the right arg at the line ```var body = Expression.OrElse(left.Body, right.Body);``` be ```rightBody```? I say so because ```rightBody``` is never used, not that I have got more knowledge about Expressions :)

Comment: @Yusif Of course not, I'd never post such a silly... uh... I would... um... damnit. It compiled, it produced a thing that looked right, but I didn't actually test the predicate. My bad... fixed. Also: well spotted. And you thought this was hard :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```cs
query.Where(n => (!includeFilter1 || <expression1>) &&
                 (!includeFilter2 || <expression2>))
```

Comment: If both are included that would require both expressions to be true which does not seem to be what the OP wants.